# Unit testing django serializers

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, serialization, pytest-django

I'm trying to unit test serializers but I have an issue in getting the expected error messages when I do serializers.is_valid().

Code:

serializer.py

```
class RandomSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    sno = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    description = serializers.CharField(required=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RandomSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

....
```

test_serializer.py

```
def test_random_serializer():
    val_dict = {'sno': 1, 'description':'test'}
    serializer = RandomSerializer(val_dict)
```

At this point when I check serializer.is_valid(), this evaluates to False and I get the following error when I check serializer.errors

```
 {u'non_field_errors': [u'No input provided']}
```

How can I fix this? Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance

PS: I also tried serializer = RandomSerializer(data=val_dict) but this does not even populate values to serializers.data

Comment: this [should](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/2228) help you, check xordoquy answer, it should give you an idea how to test your serializers

Answer (score 0):

Edit your test view like this,

```
def test_random_serializer(): 
    val_dict = {'sno': 1, 'description':'test'} 
    serializer = RandomSerializer(data=val_dict)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        return serializer.data # assertion test here....
    return serializer.errors
```

Comment: My point is the error message always evaluates to {u'non_field_errors': [u'No input provided']} which is not the one I expected. Could please elaborate on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

When I build a model serializer, I use this way:

```
class RandomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    fields = ('sno', 'description')
```

I guess defining such a tuple also works in non-model serializers.